# Authenticator breaking when refreshing tokens with coroutines runBlocking

Tags: okhttp, kotlin-coroutines

I have this nondeterministic bug in production and I can't pin it down with a minimal example
My setup is okhttp, which drives Retrofit, which uses coroutines adapter
I use Authenticator to refresh tokens and retry the requests, something like this

```kotlin
fun Authenticator.authenticate() {
    ...
    synchronized(this) {
        runBlocking { retrofitService.suspendingRefreshTokens() }<--- 
        ...
    }
}
```

What however SOMETIMES happens is that the api call just doesn't finish, as if the coroutines were broken.
I searched the internets and there seem to be some folks affected by this as well

[Using Coroutine runblock with the Authenticator to handle 401 response from retrofit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62950438/using-coroutine-runblock-with-the-authenticator-to-handle-401-response-from-retr)

Any intuition on what could be happening? I was thinking it was some sort of a deadlock because of the synchronized, however runBlocking seems to switch back to the original context, so it should be the same thread (atleast it appears that way in testing)

This never happened before with rxjava, where I used the same blockingGet() way to keep it blocking inside Authenticator; However rxjava retrofit adapter didn't use the async parameter; which leads me to believe it possibly could be a issue with Okhttp's threadpools somehow; rather than runBlocking? (which I also read is buggy)

Comment: This appears to be a coroutines question, not an OkHttp question?

Comment: @JesseWilson Not really, it's possible in any async framework, even rxjava with retrofitadapter set to async true. I'd say it's interaction of okhttp backed retrofit when using okhttp threadpool. I mean the deadlock is pretty obvious (okhttp thread trying to spawn another okhttp thread), but what I think you should provide some guidance, i.e. only use synchornous call inside interceptors etc, because I'm almost sure most of people do it like this, as you can see from the article (just first off google)

Comment: Got it. Yeah I think that’s great advice: only use synchronous calls inside interceptors!

Comment: btw your colleague from the github issue told me not to do blocking io in interceptors though

Comment: was there a response to this question?